# Understanding Logging in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

```
log4j.rootLogger=${hadoop.root.logger}
log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-6p %c{2} %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}
```

I see the following properties set in my application log properties. What does ${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file} mean? How will I come up with the log files destination looking aat these properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can 
echo ${hadoop.log.dir} or echo ${hadoop.log.file} to see the path of the directory.

Comment: It is not working. Moreover, the question is how do we translate to that value rather that what will be the value